# Unable to restore nuget packages in TFS pipeline

Tags: tfs

Unable to restore nuget packages (can't be found) in TFS pipeline even though the packages are showing up in nuget package manager for solution.
[image]
[image]

Expecting the nuget packages to be restored in the pipeline similar to ow we do it using nuget package manager for solution.

Comment: Hi @GlenChia, may i know if there's any update? The correct package version is `8133.17` not `8131.17`, details in my reply. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

As per the log, you are `nuget restore` the package from two `public` feed sources.

I can reproduce the error with you, it's caused by the package version `14.4.8131.17` is not correct. The nearest version should be `14.4.8131.30` and `14.4.8133.17`(notice 8133 here). Please fix the package version in your config file or csproj file.

[image]